# Conditional PHP unserialize function

Tags: php, serialization, deserialization

First of all, I am sorry if this appears to be a silly question. I am new with this "unserialize" command and I have been reading much information here about it, but I still really don't know how to implement it to get what I need.

Let me explain what do I have now, and what do I need.

I have this code now:

```
$consultametacat = $wpdb->get_row("
    SELECT post_id,
           meta_key,
           meta_value
      FROM cg_postmeta
     WHERE post_id = '".$consultapost->ID."' 
       AND meta_key LIKE '_category_permalink'
    ",
    ARRAY_A
);
```

This saves the results of that query to the database in ARRAY_A

Then I get that value on other lines like these:

```
$category_color = get_tax_meta($consultametacat['meta_value'],'pm_color_field_id');
$category_name = get_term_by('id', $consultametacat['meta_value'], 'category',ARRAY_A);
$category_name = get_term_by('id', $consultametacat['meta_value'], 'category',ARRAY_A);
$category_link=get_category_link($consultametacat['meta_value']);
```

It worked good so far, as the meta_value was an integer number until two weeks ago. Now, old entries in "_category_permalink" field in the database has integer numbers, but new entries have serialized data like this:

```
a:1:{s:8:"category";s:2:"23";}
```

So, what I need to do is to put a condition and unserialize according to that condition, to always get an integer number. The logic will be like this:

-if the results for

```
$consultametacat = $wpdb->get_row("
     SELECT post_id,
            meta_key,
            meta_value
       FROM cg_postmeta
      WHERE post_id = '".$consultapost->ID."'
        AND meta_key
       LIKE '_category_permalink'
     ",
     ARRAY_A
);
```

is an integer number, then save that value normally. But if it results in a serialized line, then unserialize, get the numeric value (in my example, the 23 from the line a:1:{s:8:"category";s:2:"23";}) and save that numeric value.

How to achieve this?

Thank you very much for all your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to detect first that your result is serialized and then take care of that, if not nothing more is to do:

```
if(strpos($consultametacat,':{')!==false){
  $consultametacat = unserialize($consultametacat);
  $consultametacat = array_shift($consultametacat);//or = $consultametacat['category'];
}
```

`strpos()` detects `:{` in `$consultametacat` and returns his position and every serialized data has this part in it. But `serialize()` can also serialize objects and other types, so research for yourself a little more on that topic.

Comment: Thank you very much, JOUM! This is the code that did the trick: if(strpos($consultametacat['meta_value'],':{')!==false){
  $consultametacat = unserialize($consultametacat['meta_value']);
  $consultametacat['meta_value'] = $consultametacat['category'];
}